# Update column of html table using (nested) ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, nested, html-table

I'm willing to create something like below:

Send multiple emails with employees leave cards records document as attachment. Kind of report, send these to the selected employees(selected using check box)

For this I have following sequence:

1.Draw Table with summary -  Afterwards update status of the mail failure/success

2.Get details of employee

3.Create document with received above details

4.Then send the email.

**Problem:
I want the status to be updated as soon as response is received. Now this updates after my all processing is completed.**

Code:

```
for(i=0;i< recordsTotalCount;i++)
{
  $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "getEmployeeDetails.php",
        success: function(data) {
            alert(data);
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "createDocument.php",
                success: function(data) {
                alert(data);
                   $.ajax({
                     type: "POST",
                     url: "sendEmailWithAttachament.php",
                     success: function(data) {
                     alert(data);
                    $("#i").html(data); // Update column with received response true/false
                     }
                  });
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Please guide for this, what can be done? To update the status like real time displaying the status. Any other suggestions to achieve this kind of things are welcome.

Thanks!

Comment: well, you do receive the updated #i element at the end and also get the data alerts? you put the $("#i").html(data) in the last ajax query callback - why don't you add it in each success method before you call the next ajax function? also, you're using POST while you aren't passing any parameters which isn't a good practice..

Comment: Thanks! I tried to give brief of the problem statement, also I have used the things you have mentioned. But yes, I'll try to update in next ajax call.. :)

Comment: @gulty: It doesn't sort my problem. Thanks for the help!

Comment: But you are getting the correct/expected alert(data) values when each request finishes? and when all your requests are done your #i is showing the expected response? the only thing which doesn't show up are the steps between?

Comment: yes, it does show all correct data.

Comment: Then I still dont see where your problem is. If it shows the response in an alert it also shows it in your #i div element. maybe it just updates the div too fast so you won't be able to see it? if you add $("#i").html(data); in your first ajax it's updatin the div and you get your first response? then it works if you add it for all of them...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55758/discussion-between-emma-and-gulty).